# Why the number '0' (number, not char) doesn't displaying?

Tags: c

The problem is that I cannot see **0** in an array.

I run my program and see 2D array. But instead of **0** (the first element) I see nothing.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int *Ptr;

    scanf("%d%d", &M, &N); /* Size of array. */

    Ptr = malloc(M*N*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < M * N; i++) /* Filling in. */
    {
        *(Ptr + i) = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M * N; i++) /* Displaying. */
    {
        if (i % N == 0)
            printf("\n");
        printf("%2.d  ", *(Ptr + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?
Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: It seems that 0 exists (the first element of array is '0', the 2-nd element = '1' and so on...)

Comment: The dot in the `printf` format string, remove it.

Comment: Thnx! This is very helpful comment.
But why don't you "Answer" the quiestion? If you did so, I would be able to "Accept" it.

Comment: If you're going to give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), pay attention to *all* of the criteria. This codes isn't *compilable*...

Comment: >>> This codes isn't compilable..
 
ME: I don't understand why..

>>> If you're going to give us an SSCCE
 
ME: I'm not trying to do something else beside of trying to solve the problem. And I cannot understand whether it is good or bad remark for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number after the dot is the precision. If the precision is 0 (or does not exist) then printf does not print out `0`. In your case you do not need the dot:

```
printf("%2d ", ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
printf("%2.d  ", *(Ptr + i));
```

to

```
printf("%2d  ", *(Ptr + i));
```